# how to acess global variable in function of r

Tags: r

Here I am using data frame temp as global variable by using "<<- " symbol.I expected to get value global variable value changes affect in every function.but it not working.

my code is

```
vf<-function()
{
  df<<-data.frame(A=c(2),B=c(3))
  vk(df)
  print(df)
}

vk<-function(df)
{
  lk<-data.frame(C=c(3),D=c(4))
  df<<-cbind(df,lk)
}
```

nothing happened after function call.

expected output is

```
>vf()
A  B C D
2  3 3 4
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: Can you make the code concise ?

Comment: there are two function present in this code vf and vk.Second function(vk) is called by vf.During function call of vk, values in the  data frame(L2_table) changes.
first function vf contain a data frame df.create new data frame "temp" with df's 1st column as "temp's column name" and second column of df as its corresponding row values.
when i called the function vk ,same procedure take place[instead of df ,L2_table vlaues] and values saved in same temp data frame.but each time temp value is over writing.That is the problem.i need append values each time in temp data frame.

Comment: @phoxis .did you understand question ?

Comment: Not clear at all. But your call vk(i) in vf() is totally useless since it does not return anything nor change any global variable.

Comment: @KarlForner.then how can i change the global variable value ??

Comment: @KarlForner.i edited my code and now its more clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code works perfectly :-) The only part you miss if you want to use a global variable, you must declare it globally.

Here's my output:

```
> df <- NULL
> vf <- function()
{
  df <<- data.frame(A=c(2),B=c(3))
  vk(df)
  print(df)
}
> vk <- function(df)
{
  lk <- data.frame(C=c(3),D=c(4))
  df <<- cbind(df,lk)
}
> vf()
  A B C D
1 2 3 3 4
```

So what you miss is to add a `df <- NULL` declaration

---

You can do the same w/o a global variable, it's a bit cleaner:

```
vf <- function()
{
  df <- data.frame(A=c(2),B=c(3))
  vk(df) # Same as 'return(vk(df))'
}

vk <- function(df)
{
  lk <- data.frame(C=c(3),D=c(4))
  cbind(df,lk) # Same as 'return(cbind(df,lk))'
}

vf() # Returns value, not stored --> printed on the output
newGlobal <- vf() # Stores the value returned by vf()
```

**By the way, if you interested in R, you can find a list of great books about common snippets and traps here:**

http://xcafebabe.blogspot.hu/2011/09/free-r-book-collection.html

Comment: @rlegendi.if i short the code .I cant get the ouput what i want reduce code as it maximum now,.what i need is  first temp contain a ,b,c and its value 2 4 3.if i call the function vk, temp become colname(a,b,c,d,e,f) and values 2 4 3 4 4 3

Comment: @rlegendi.I edited code.i need global variable changes in function vk will affected in vf

Comment: i clearly edited what i want .can you please help me .how can i use global varible ??

Comment: :D.thanks .is it possible to store value instead of global variable?. I meant;by using return value.return(df) ?? possible

Comment: @user3090597 Updated post again ;-)